# Angular 2 - How to select a newly created element

Tags: angular

I have the following template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let block of selectedItem.blocks;let index=index">
  <td>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" class="idx-{{index}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.blocks[index].min" name="{{'minimum'+index}}">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn" (click)="addBlock()">Add Block</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem I'm having seems to be with the `addBlock()` method:

```
addBlock() {
    this.selectedItem.blocks.push(new Block({
      minimum: this.selectedItem.blocks.length
        ? this.selectedItem.blocks[this.selectedItem.blocks.length - 1].maximum
        : 0
    }));

    this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.idx-' + this.selectedItem.blocks.length - 1).focus();
}
```

For some reason `this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector` isn't able to see the newly created element.  Is there something I need to do that will wait to execute the querySelector until after the element has been added.

**UPDATE:**
`this.elRef` is an instance of `ElementRef`:

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}
```

Comment: what is `this.elRef`?

Comment: Can you describe what `this.elRef` doing here ? Your code is not clear.

Comment: @Maximus @Harshit it's an instance of `ElementRef`.  I updated the question as well.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a working demo. I hope that it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try making your component `implements` `AfterViewChecked` and inside `ngAfterViewChecked`, do your stuff

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.idx-' + this.selectedItem.blocks.length - 1).focus();
}
```